# Query the Windows registry through batch syntax

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I'm trying to query a particular registry folder (or whatever you want to call it) to obtain some information.

Particularly the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` folder contains a list of installed software.

The issue is that each software is identified through a random key value like `{0001B4FD-9EA3-4D90-A79E-FD14BA3AB01D}` instead of the actual software (like `Skype`).

This makes it hard to find the `Skype` identifier because I need to loop through everything inside this `Uninstall` folder and check whether the `DisplayName` value corresponds to `Skype` (or whatever other application name).

I need to use batch syntax... this is what I have so far but it doesn't behave the same on different computers, maybe I get different variables assigned based on some erroneous formatting of the reg output? I don't know. Can I use a data structure to contain whatever `reg` outputs? Anything would work.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall') do (
    for /f "tokens=2,* delims= " %%b in ('reg query %%a /v Publisher') do (
        IF "%%c" == "Skype Technologies S.A." (
            for /f "tokens=2,* delims= " %%d in ('reg query %%a /v UninstallString') do (
                echo %%e
            )
        )
    )

)
```

Is there a cleaner and safer way to achieve this in batch?

Comment: Perhaps you are better off asking this on ServerFault. About your data structure, just writing it to a temporary file isn't enough I assume?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems me more easy to use

```
reg QUERY HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall  /f "Skype Technologies S.A." /s
```

as a basis for your batch file. It produces a simple output like following

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{D103C4BA-F905-437A-8049-DB24763BBE36}
    Publisher    REG_SZ    Skype Technologies S.A.

End of search: 1 match(es) found.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is sort of what I was looking for. Can I make it to show all values under that search result (not only the matched Publisher value)? I need th UninstallString value which doesn't contain any 'skype' reference... what do you suggest for such task? Should I just query it again based on `{D103C4BA-F905-437A-8049-DB24763BBE36}` ?

Comment: @Luca Matteis: You ask new a new question. You should describe more in detail what you really need. I suggested you to reduce the loops with one call of reg.exe. Evry call of reg.exe is slow, Batch work also slow. With 3 loops one inside another your program will **at least** 1000 times slower. So if you need not exactly what you asked in your question you should describe more exactly **what you really need**. Could you use only Batch and nothing more? VBS, PowerShell or a simple C program which very simple and do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This batch loop through items under the Uninstall key and search for the defined software name e.g. Skype. Once it located the software and the full key, it will then use it to search and print out **DisplayName** and **UninstallString** as shown in Output below.

Note:

1. For some software e.g. Skype, Notepad++ the key may not contain a GUID e.g. {BEB5FB69-4080-466F-96C4-F15DF271718B}. This batch is able to find software with or without a GUID
2. It can return multiple software if the name is too short
3. Use %x86GUID% variable to search 32 bit software and %x64GUID% for 64 bit software

.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set SoftwareName=Skype
set x86GUID=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
set x64GUID=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

REM It's faster to first locate the software GUID, then search it's Name, Version & UninstallString
for /f "delims=" %%P in ('reg query "%x86GUID%" /s /f "%SoftwareName%" 2^>nul ^| findstr "Uninstall\\%SoftwareName% Uninstall\\{"') do (
  echo %%P
  for /f "tokens=2*" %%A in ('reg query "%%P" /v "DisplayName" 2^>nul ^|findstr "DisplayName"') do echo Found: %%B
  for /f "tokens=2*" %%A in ('reg query "%%P" /v "UninstallString" 2^>nul ^|findstr "UninstallString"') do echo %%B 
)
endlocal
```

**Output**

```
Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Skype_is1
DisplayName: Skype version 8.64
UninstallString: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop\unins000.exe"
```